# iOS Equivalent of Pulse and Wait for Threading

Tags: ios, multithreading

I am looking for an equivalent pattern in multi-threading in iOS as there is in .NET for pulse and wait.  Essentially, I want a background thread to lay dormant until a flag is set, which essentially "kicks" the thread into action.

It is an alternative to a loop+thread.sleep().  The flag can be set on a different thread than the actual background thread doing the processing.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't do that, it's a bad model. Unless you have some very specific reason to care which thread does a job, use a thread pool. When you want a job done, queue it to the pool. Otherwise, you waste threads, waste resources, and force extra context switches.

Comment: There have been a number of suggestions (NSThread, GCD's semaphore, etc.). I like David's suggestion above, the best, which is rather than setting some flag that some other thread is waiting to detect changes, just do a simple `dispatch_async()` to kick off whatever process is going to do the processing. No muss. No fuss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of different mix-and-match thread APIs available on iOS and OS X. What are you using to create your thread?

The simplest suggestion is to use a [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) semaphore](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_semaphore_create).

Setup code:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
// Then make sure your thread has access to this semaphore
```

Thread code:

```
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
// Will block forever until the semaphore is triggered
```

Trigger code:

```
dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
```

An even better suggestion: GCD already manages its own thread pool, so just take advantage of it instead of spinning up your own thread. It's very easy to use `dispatch_async` to run some code in a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this pattern in .NET, but it is generally a bad idea to purposefully lock a thread (unless that thread cannot continue, but it sounds like you want it waiting most of the time or at least for long periods of time).

This is bad for the scheduler, bad for system resources.

You can use NSThread's +detachNewThreadSelector:... method to make a new thread.  And you can use a variety of ideas to try to manage your logic for creating and maintaining such a thread in a single place like NSObject's -performSelectorOnMainThread:...

Comment: Correct.  Basically, I have a background scheduler that executes tasks in a serial fashion, but on a separate thread than the main thread.  Each one of these tasks depends on an Internet connection. If the internet connection is down, I do not want to execute these tasks (or poll).  I would like for it to pause and wait until internet connectivity is back up.

Comment: So make a method intended only to be hit on the main thread that would be something like -internetConnectionDown and call it to clean up your threads and register for a NSNotification when the internet is available again.  Then you can create your child threads and let them do their things again.  Note that this is not the same as blocking on those child threads until the internet connection is up.  I propose you tear down the child threads if internet connection is not found and set them up when it is.